# React JS Help: Calling react-papaparse function results in infinite loop of calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I am developing a webapp to visualize some data from a remote csv. I found that react papaparse can help in this. Here is my code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'; 
import { DataContext } from '../context/DataContext';
import { readRemoteFile } from 'react-papaparse'

const India = () => {
    const { data, dispatch } = useContext(DataContext);
    const fetchData = () => {
        readRemoteFile('https://www.example.com/abc.csv', {
          complete: (results) => {

            dispatch(
                {type:'UPDATE_DATA', data:results}
            )

            console.log(data)
          }
        })
      }
    return(
        <div className="container">
            {fetchData()}
        </div>
    )

}
export default India;
```

When I run this it keeps logging the "data" object infinitely till the server returns 500 error or my system results in some error. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Make the reuqest inside `useEffect`, or bind with a callback

Comment: useEffect too returns in infinite loop unless I pass a second empty parameter [ ]. Also it makes my whole code messy because I want to use the data object for displaying data in a rechart component. I have to put use ternary operator two times (to set the data for charts and to actually display the chart). I even used a class based component and still facing same error.